# Is this division of complex sequence bounded?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $ \{z_n\}_{n \in N} $ be a sequence of complex numbers $ C $

I would like to know if  $\frac{|\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{z_n}|}{\sqrt{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{|z_n|^2}}} $ is bounded.

Thanks.

Any suggestion is welcome

Comment: No, it is not bounded. Set $z_n=\frac1n$ to get the standard example.

Comment: From a "functional analysis" point of view, it would imply $\ell^2\subseteq \ell^1$, which is not the case.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli It would imply $\ell^1\subset \ell^2$ not the converse.

Comment: @LeBtz Well, $\ell^1\subseteq \ell^2$ is always true. $\ddot\smile$ My idea was: pick a (w.l.o.g.) positive sequence $z\notin \ell^1$. Then the inequality becomes $+\infty=\lVert z\rVert_1\le C\lVert z\rVert_2$. Since $C\ne 0$, it must hold $\lVert z\rVert_2=+\infty$.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli You are Right, I mixed things up.

Answer (score 1):

No. Let $z_n=1$ for all $n$, and your partial sums become $\sqrt n$, which is unbounded.